# Pegar data-src de imagem aberta no lightGallery

Tags: jquery

Preciso pegar o `data-src` do item aberto da galeria, conforme o usuário vai avançando as fotos na galeria, um input deve ser atualizado.

```
    <div class="item " data-src="assets/img/tour/-11521134609.jpg" data-sub-html="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <img alt="" src="assets/img/tour/-11521134609.jpg"><br>
    </div>
        <div class="item " data-src="assets/img/tour/-445452345.jpg" data-sub-html="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <img alt="" src="assets/img/tour/-445452345.jpg"><br>
        </div>
    <div class="item " data-src="assets/img/tour/-asdfasdfasdf.jpg" data-sub-html="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
        <img alt="" src="assets/img/tour/-asdfasdfasdf.jpg"><br>
    </div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $lg = $('#captions').lightGallery({
            mode: 'lg-fade',
                width: '800px',
                height: '700px',
                addClass: 'fixed-size',
                counter: false,
                startClass: '',
                enableSwipe: false,
                enableDrag: false,
                speed: 500,
                closable:true,
                download: false,
                share: false,
                thumbnail:false,
                autoplay: false,
                actualSize: false,
                fullScreen: false,
                zoom:false
        }); 
            $lg.on('onAfterSlide.lg', function (event ) {
                console.log( $lg.data('lightGallery').$items.eq(0).data('src') );
            });
    });
```

O retorno no console está sendo sempre `assets/img/tour/-11521134609.jpg` que é o nome da primeira imagem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade você não precisa pegar o `data-src`, porque o valor desse atributo é o caminho da imagem que vai ser exibida no slider, logo, basta pegar o src da imagem atual que está sendo exibida.

Agora, como o componente constrói a div de forma dinâmica no slider, o evento `onAfterSlide.lg` não consegue ter uma sincronia perfeita com essa ação, ou seja, o evento pode ser disparado antes do componente construir a div que exibe a imagem maior.

Em vista disso, vi a necessidade de usar um temporizador `setInterval` para verificar quando se a div que exibe a imagem já existe.

O elemento construído pelo plugin é a div com a classe `.lg-current`, portanto, após o evento ser disparado, basta verificar dentro do interval se o elemento existe e imprimir o atributo src da imagem exibida.

Veja no exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $lg = $('#captions').lightGallery({
      mode: 'lg-fade',
          width: '800px',
          height: '700px',
          addClass: 'fixed-size',
          counter: false,
          startClass: '',
          enableSwipe: false,
          enableDrag: false,
          speed: 500,
          closable:true,
          download: false,
          share: false,
          thumbnail:false,
          autoplay: false,
          actualSize: false,
          fullScreen: false,
          zoom:false
  }); 
   $lg.on('onAfterSlide.lg', function (event ) {
      var timer = setInterval(function(){
         if($(".lg-current img").length){
            console.log($(".lg-current img").attr("src"));
            clearInterval(timer);
         }
      }, 100);
   });
});
```

```css
.item{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
}

.item img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery@1.6.12/src/css/lightgallery.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lightgallery@1.6.12/dist/js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<div id="captions">
<div class="item " data-src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg?1" data-sub-html="">
        <img alt="" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg"><br>
    </div>
        <div class="item " data-src="https://libraries.acm.org/binaries/content/gallery/acm/ctas/publications/nodes-764.jpg/nodes-764.jpg/acm%3Adesktopcta?2" data-sub-html="">
            <img alt="" src="https://libraries.acm.org/binaries/content/gallery/acm/ctas/publications/nodes-764.jpg/nodes-764.jpg/acm%3Adesktopcta"><br>
        </div>
    <div class="item " data-src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/c2/5b/2a/nature-1-15-largejpg.jpg?3" data-sub-html="">
        <img alt="" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/09/c2/5b/2a/nature-1-15-largejpg.jpg"><br>
    </div>
</div>
```